# Entity framework code-first ignores table mapping

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

We have a ef project using an existing legacy database, but adding new tables to it using ef-migrations. For these entities, we create tables using a new schema, to separate them from the legacy tables. We use the convention with plural form of the class name on the db tables.
However, when we add a new class to be mapped to a legacy table (without a plural table name), ef seems to ignore the mapping.
The entity class:

```
public class Aktor:IVersionedEntityWithId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Navn { get; set; }
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping code:

```
    protected virtual void MapAktor(EntityTypeConfiguration<Tilsyn.Domain.Aktor> config){
        config.ToTable("dbo.Aktor");
        config.Property(v=>v.Version).IsConcurrencyToken().IsRowVersion(); 
        config.HasKey(e=>e.Id); 
    }
```

The exception:

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while
>   executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Aktors'.

It seems like the sql generated still ad an s to the class name to get the table name. What is missing in this picture? Am I using the `ToTable` method wrong?

Update: When changing the class name to something other than the table name, it seems to work. When changing the name back again, the problem has vansihed. Is there a EF cache or hidden mapping file somwehere?

Comment: BTW: `ToTable` has a 2-parameter overload to map table and schema name: `config.ToTable("Aktor", "dbo")`. But it probably has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try overriding OnModelCreating() method in your DBContext subclass to create your mappings.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tilsyn.Domain.Aktor>().ToTable("dbo.Aktor");
}
```

Comment: I see that this isn't obvious from my snippets, but that is in fact what we are doing.

Comment: Looks completely different to me

Comment: Yes, I know it does. I generate a mapping class using T4 from all entity classes, and the method in the snippet is called from OnModelCreated. Trust me:)

Comment: OK and when you debug is it being called?

Comment: Yes. Note the update to the question; when changing the class name, the problem disappears. Perhaps just a framework glitch.